# android per-recorded words library that can talk

Tags: java, android, voice

i am trying to write a program sample that can talk according to some signals 
for example if some one pressed a specific button the program says "hello".

my question is there any list or library that contains already recorded words - as voice - in android ?

Comment: It not home work this a small part of a big project  if the library existing why should i record the words that i need

Comment: Android TTS maybe?